# SDK dynamically use class in hosted app in iOS with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, cocoapods

I developing an iOS SDK(Let's call it A) and it will be used by host app via Cocoapod. In my SDK I need to use a class in another SDK(Let's call it B), host app already include a copy of B' SDK and use it in their codes.

The problem is in my own SDK A how can I dynamically find and use the SDK B which has been included in the host app? I cannot include another copy of B's SDK in A for the SDK size issue.

The language is objective-C.

Thanks!

Comment: What about using `dependency` in the podspec referring to SDK B?

Comment: It will still download the SDK B when pod install A in hosted app